# css width adjust

Tags: css, position, fluid-layout

I want that a div as a certain width (80%) in all resolution, and browser resize this div resize too, only the width. I must work only width css, no javascript

I have this:

```
 #container{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:80%;
    height:401px;
    outline:solid 1px red;
}
```

When I resize or see in lower resolution this div becomes above others.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you can use z-index to manage overlays

Comment: "becomes above others" Did you mean the layer stacking? If yes try [z-index](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index)

Answer (score 2):

Change `z-index` or change positioning, cause `absolute` means this div dosen't matter about other elements and can cover them.